# Where does chrome store its session cookies?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, cookies, session-cookies

I have a macOS. I want to export the 11 cookies with domain `.facebook.com` that is stored by Google Chrome.

I want to know where Chrome stores session cookies. I am using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookies/iphcomljdfghbkdcfndaijbokpgddeno/ to read my cookies. I want to know where these are stored. Upon searching the web, I found that it is stored in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/` as `Cookies` as a `sqlite3` file. Upon reading it I seemed convinced that it is the same cookies.

When I delete all my cookies in `chrome://settings/content/cookies` or via the extension, I am logged out of facebook. However the file `Cookies` in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/` is unchanged. It has a unchanged timestamp of yesterday.

How do I export my current cookies from chrome? When I removed the file `Cookies` and reloaded facebook, I was still signed in. So, thats not the Cookie.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue where I want to delete cookies programmatically, but this isn't the right file...